# Trying to add complicated article in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a article tag into my html using jquery's .html or .append.

```
$('.tasks').html('
    <article>
    <a><img src="img/details.png"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/urgent.png"></a>
    <h1>Mar.</h1>
    <a href="#"><img class="cal" src="img/cal.png"></a>
    <h1>Week 2 Project</h1>
    </article>
');
```

maybe you can not use the .html or append this way? I have tried breaking it up using concatenations as well.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot have a new line character in a string literal like that

You can either use `\` at the end of the line to indicate that the string literal continues in the next line

```
$('.tasks').html(' \
    <article>\
    <a><img src="img/details.png"></a>\
    <a href="#"><img src="img/urgent.png"></a>\
    <h1>Mar.</h1>\
    <a href="#"><img class="cal" src="img/cal.png"></a>\
    <h1>Week 2 Project</h1>\
    </article>\
');
```

or use string concatenation

```
$('.tasks').html('<article>' +
    '<a><img src="img/details.png"></a>' +
    '<a href="#"><img src="img/urgent.png"></a>' +
    '<h1>Mar.</h1>' +
    '<a href="#"><img class="cal" src="img/cal.png"></a>' +
    '<h1>Week 2 Project</h1>' + 
    '</article>');
```